# Over-occupying the CPU by the software

Tags: cpu

Sometimes when I open the Premier software, a large number of my computer CPUs are consumed in vain, but nothing happens in the Premier software, nor does it give any instructions to the software that consumes the computer CPU. Be. Even if I spend an hour consuming CPU like this, it is of no use. This occupation of the computer CPU causes problems in the software, which causes many of the features of the Premier software to not work well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. We only accept programming-related questions in this site, you may want to ask in [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) you may find your answers there.

Comment: Hi, one of my friends introduced this site and said that I might answer you. I have a hacked version of Premier and I can not contact support. (My country is under sanctions and I can not buy the original version) I thought maybe you could introduce me to another site similar to this site so I can find the answers to my questions there. thank you

Comment: This https://superuser.com/help/on-topic - SUPER USER, you can ask your question there.